# filtering StackTraceElement when printStackTrace

Tags: java

I use spring. I have many bundles with chaining dependency.

*mvc bundle* --> (calls) *biz bundle* --> *core bundle* --> *common bundle* --> *remote RPC service*

All bundles are loaded in the same JVM. But *mvc bundle* doesn't call *biz bundle*'s object directly, instead *biz bundle* publishes the service by exposing an interface to *mvc bundle*. *mvc bundle* has a proxy object, and the proxy object calls the service implementation object.

my stacktrace looks like this:

```
...
at com.mycorp.kbdatacenter.common.service.integration.nomo.NomoDataServiceClientImpl.getPropertyDistribution(NomoDataServiceClientImpl.java:64) ~[kbdatacenter-common-service-integration-1.0.0.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
at com.mycorp.sofa.runtime.service.binding.JvmBindingAdapter$JvmServiceInvoker$1.call(JvmBindingAdapter.java:87) ~[?:?]
at com.mycorp.ambush.chain.codewrapper.CodeWrapperInvocationImpl.proceed(CodeWrapperInvocationImpl.java:77) ~[ambush-1.0.10.jar:?]
at com.mycorp.guardian.client.sofa.GuardianCodeWrapperInterceptor.invokeCodeWrapper(GuardianCodeWrapperInterceptor.java:76) ~[guardian-sofa-1.1.5.jar:?]
at com.mycorp.ambush.chain.codewrapper.CodeWrapperInvocationImpl.proceed(CodeWrapperInvocationImpl.java:71) ~[ambush-1.0.10.jar:?]
at com.mycorp.ambush.catalog.AbstractCatalog.doIntercept(AbstractCatalog.java:252) ~[ambush-1.0.10.jar:?]
at com.mycorp.ambush.api.AmbushRPCUtil.invokeClient(AmbushRPCUtil.java:79) ~[ambush-1.0.10.jar:?]
at com.mycorp.sofa.runtime.service.binding.JvmBindingAdapter$JvmServiceInvoker.doInvoke(JvmBindingAdapter.java:90) ~[?:?]
at com.mycorp.sofa.runtime.service.component.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:29) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.getPropertyDistribution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.mycorp.kbdatacenter.core.service.tag.TagDataQueryServiceImpl.queryByFilterRule(TagDataQueryServiceImpl.java:105) ~[kbdatacenter-core-service-1.0.0.jar:?]
... (119 lines more)
```

My *core bundle* has a proxy object *nomoDataServiceClient* which calls *Impl* object in *common bundle*.

My question is, is it possible to filter StackTraceElement[], ignore packages **com.sun.proxy**, **sun.reflect** and others. I want my stackstace looks clean like this:

```
...
at com.mycorp.kbdatacenter.common.service.integration.nomo.NomoDataServiceClientImpl.getPropertyDistribution(NomoDataServiceClientImpl.java:64) ~[kbdatacenter-common-service-integration-1.0.0.jar:?]
at com.mycorp.kbdatacenter.core.service.tag.TagDataQueryServiceImpl.queryByFilterRule(TagDataQueryServiceImpl.java:105) ~[kbdatacenter-core-service-1.0.0.jar:?]
...
```

Comment: why would you do this? I see no reason to loss such info on demand - if you want to make logs 'cleaner' just catch Exception and print out custom message instead of printing whole stacktrace

Comment: Because the chain is long, so many repeated *com.sun.proxy* and *sun.reflect* make me difficult to find my useful one-line-only *com.mycorp.kbdatacenter.core* in the middle of the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. If you catch the exception, you could get the stack trace elements, create a new (filtered) array from it, and override the stacktrace of the exception, for example

```
try {
  //your exception throwing call here
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.setStackTrace(Arrays.stream(e.getStackTrace())
                        .filter(se -> !se.getClassName().startsWith("com.sun.proxy")) //or any other filter criteria
                        .collect(toList())
                        .toArray(new StackTraceElement[0])); //create a new stacktrace from the filtered list
  //either e.printStackStrace();
  //or rethrow
}
```

Comment: Gerald, nice code. Look at my answer though and I provide the open source library that does it. you might like it. My library doesn't modify the exception itself, but just filters the stacktrace and provides it as a String

Comment: Brilliant. You could notice: `Collectors.toList()`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I wrote an Open source java library that does exactly what you are asking for. It is available as maven artifact and as git repository, so you can just use it as a third party library or take the code itself. Basically if you use it as third party library you will need to set your prefix as "com.mycorp." and then just use the method `TextUtils.getStacktrace(e)` and it will give you filtered out stacktrace as a String. Here is the reference to the article that explains where to get the library and how to use it. [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman). See paragraph "**Stacktrace noise filter**" It is very easy to use this library. Here is a fragment of pom file that holds maven dependencies to the library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.michaelgantman</groupId>
        <artifactId>MgntUtils</artifactId>
        <version>1.04</version> 
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.michaelgantman</groupId>
        <artifactId>MgntUtils</artifactId>
        <version>1.04</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier> 
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.michaelgantman</groupId>
        <artifactId>MgntUtils</artifactId>
        <version>1.04</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Liked Gerald's answer, however trying to use it in Jira's Scriptrunner plugin - it had some issues with the lambda.
Wanted to also share my version, which is based on [Groovy Goodness: Java 8 Stream Enhancements](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2018/06/groovy-goodness-java-8-stream.html), and is aimed at printing the exception into log.
Overall it had reduced the huge 370 line stack trace I was getting into 12 lines pertaining only to my code itself.

```
catch (Throwable err) {
log.error(
"""Exception occurred while handling SQL request.
${org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils.extractRootCause(err)}
\tat ${err.stackTrace.stream()
                     .filter { s -> !(s.getClassName().startsWith('com.atlassian') || 
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('com.sun.jersey') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('com.onresolve.scriptrunner.automation') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('com.codebarrel.jira.plugin.automation') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('com.codebarrel.automation.api') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('org.codehaus') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('org.apache') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('org.tuckey') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('javax.script') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('java.util.concurrent') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('java.lang.Thread') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('groovy.lang') ||
                                      s.getClassName().startsWith('groovy.console') ||
                                      s.getClassName().toLowerCase().contains('reflect')) }
                     .toList().join("\n\tat ")}""")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the stacktrace and then print it. It's important to filter the stacktraces of the entire chain of exceptions, as well as supressed exceptions.

Below is a simple demo of how it can be implemented, defined to show the first and last 2 lines of each stacktrace, as well as lines that match a package and the lines before and after the matched lines. If there're one or more skipped lines, it shows a single `...` instead.

```java
package my.package.util;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class LogUtils {
    private static class MyException extends Exception {
        public MyException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    private static void cleanStackTraces(Throwable current, String[] classes) {
        final String[] classesToUse = (classes != null) ? classes : new String[0];

        while (current != null) {
            StackTraceElement[] elements = current.getStackTrace();
            List<Boolean> idxs = IntStream.range(0, elements.length)
                .mapToObj(idx -> {
                    StackTraceElement se = elements[idx];
                    if (classesToUse.length > 0) {
                        for (String clazz : classesToUse) {
                            if (se.getClassName().startsWith(clazz)) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }

                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }).toList();

            List<StackTraceElement> newElements = new ArrayList<>();
            boolean showMore = false;

            for (int idx = 0; idx < idxs.size(); idx++) {
                StackTraceElement se = elements[idx];

                if (idxs.get(idx)) {
                    showMore = false;
                    newElements.add(se);
                } else {
                    boolean startLines = (idx <= 1);
                    boolean endLines = (idx >= idxs.size() - 2);
                    boolean beforeMatch = (idx < idxs.size() - 1) ? idxs.get(idx + 1) : false;
                    boolean afterMatch = (idx > 0) ? idxs.get(idx - 1) : false;

                    if (startLines || endLines || beforeMatch || afterMatch) {
                        showMore = true;
                        newElements.add(se);
                    } else if (showMore) {
                        showMore = false;
                        se = new StackTraceElement("", "..", "", -1);
                        newElements.add(se);
                    }
                }
            }

            current.setStackTrace(newElements.toArray(new StackTraceElement[0]));

            Throwable[] suppressed = current.getSuppressed();

            if (suppressed != null) {
                for (Throwable t : suppressed) {
                    cleanStackTraces(t, classesToUse);
                }
            }

            current = current.getCause();
        }
    }

    private static void throwException1() throws MyException {
        throw new MyException("Test error...");
    }

    private static void throwException2() throws MyException {
        throwException1();
    }

    private static void throwException3() throws MyException {
        throwException2();
    }

    private static void throwException4() throws MyException {
        throwException3();
    }

    private static void throwException5() throws MyException {
        throwException4();
    }

    private static void throwException() throws MyException {
        throwException5();
    }

    private static void testStackTrace(String[] classes) {
        try {
            try {
                throwException();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                try {
                    throwException();
                } catch(Exception e2) {
                    e.addSuppressed(e2);
                }

                throw new RuntimeException("Runtime error...", e);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            try {
                throwException();
            } catch(Exception e2) {
                e.addSuppressed(e2);

                try {
                    throwException();
                } catch(Exception e3) {
                    e2.addSuppressed(e3);
                }
            }

            cleanStackTraces(e, classes);
            String str = getStacktraceAsString(e);
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    private static String getStacktraceAsString(Throwable t) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String exceptionStr = sw.toString();
        exceptionStr = exceptionStr.replace("at ...()", "...");
        return exceptionStr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] defaultClasses = {"my.package"};
        System.out.println("Show package (" + Arrays.asList(defaultClasses) + ") lines:");
        System.out.println();
        testStackTrace(defaultClasses);

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();

        String[] classes = {"no.package"};
        System.out.println("No existing package defined:");
        System.out.println();
        testStackTrace(classes);
    }
}
```

Below is the printed stacktraces (the 1st case allows the package in which the class is located, allowing all lines to be printed because the entire stacktrace occurs in this file, while the 2nd case simulates a case of lines that does not match the package):

```
Show package ([my.package]) lines:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Runtime error...
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:113)
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.main(LogUtils.java:146)
        Suppressed: my.package.util.LogUtils$MyException: Test error...
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException1(LogUtils.java:79)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException2(LogUtils.java:83)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException3(LogUtils.java:87)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException4(LogUtils.java:91)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException5(LogUtils.java:95)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException(LogUtils.java:99)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:117)
                ... 1 more
                Suppressed: my.package.util.LogUtils$MyException: Test error...
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException1(LogUtils.java:79)
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException2(LogUtils.java:83)
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException3(LogUtils.java:87)
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException4(LogUtils.java:91)
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException5(LogUtils.java:95)
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException(LogUtils.java:99)
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:122)
                        ... 1 more
Caused by: my.package.util.LogUtils$MyException: Test error...
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException1(LogUtils.java:79)
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException2(LogUtils.java:83)
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException3(LogUtils.java:87)
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException4(LogUtils.java:91)
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException5(LogUtils.java:95)
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException(LogUtils.java:99)
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:105)
        ... 1 more
        Suppressed: my.package.util.LogUtils$MyException: Test error...
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException1(LogUtils.java:79)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException2(LogUtils.java:83)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException3(LogUtils.java:87)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException4(LogUtils.java:91)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException5(LogUtils.java:95)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException(LogUtils.java:99)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:108)
                ... 1 more

---------------------------------------------------------

No existing package defined:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Runtime error...
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:113)
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.main(LogUtils.java:154)
        Suppressed: my.package.util.LogUtils$MyException: Test error...
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException1(LogUtils.java:79)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException2(LogUtils.java:83)
                ...
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:117)
                ... 1 more
                Suppressed: my.package.util.LogUtils$MyException: Test error...
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException1(LogUtils.java:79)
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException2(LogUtils.java:83)
                        ...
                        at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:122)
                        ... 1 more
Caused by: my.package.util.LogUtils$MyException: Test error...
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException1(LogUtils.java:79)
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException2(LogUtils.java:83)
        ...
        at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:105)
        ... 1 more
        Suppressed: my.package.util.LogUtils$MyException: Test error...
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException1(LogUtils.java:79)
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.throwException2(LogUtils.java:83)
                ...
                at my.package.util.LogUtils.testStackTrace(LogUtils.java:108)
                ... 1 more
```

In a real scenario you would define your package to be kept in the stacktrace (like the 1st example), because you actually would want to see the lines that mention your package, while leaving out packages from external libraries, for example.

The cleaning of the stacktrace is more evident when the exception is propagated through several different packages (including external packages). This demo just gives a general idea of what it does.